# Setup custom domains on reverse proxies on IIS

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have already setup my reverse proxy on IIS to have different applications on my subdomains like

- azuredns.com/app1
- azuredns.com/app2

I want to setup a custom domain that points to each of these apps, for example

- my.domain.com points to azuredns.com/app1
- store.domain.com points to azuredns.com/app2

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know, For this scenario of each domains pointing to each of the apps with IIS, there is not a good way to achieve this. Because the DNS only resolve `xxx` section of the URL like `HTTP://xxx/app1`. After `/` partition, the IIS as a front end that receives all of the incoming app traffic distributes or redirects each of these apps to different sites.

Perhaps, as a workaround, you could try to map the custom domains to the different host name where each of these apps existed directly or only map the custom domains to azuredns.com.

Comment: Update my reply, if you have applications hosted on the Azure VM, just add two CNAME records with domain provider. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: My problem is that both cname points to the root azuredns.com. How can I specify which application to load in each subdomain?

Comment: no good way to achieve this. please see my update.